# Push() with Arrays of Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build an 'array of arrays' (think of a table with columns and rows).  I have code that loops through each 'row', and builds an array of 'columns' that it then pushes onto the array of rows:

```
var myRows = [];  // array of 'column' arrays
var myCols = [];  // 'buffer' for each column

for (r=4; r>=0; r--) {
   myCols.length = 0; 
  for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
   myCols.push("row: " + r +", col: " + c);
  }
  myRows.push(myCols);
}
console.log(myRows);
```

What I would expect from `console.log(myRows)` is something like this:

```
[Array[10], Array[10], Array[10], Array[10], Array[10]]
0: Array[10]
0: "row: 0, col: 0"
1: "row: 0, col: 1"
2: "row: 0, col: 2"
3: "row: 0, col: 3"
4: "row: 0, col: 4"
5: "row: 0, col: 5"
6: "row: 0, col: 6"
7: "row: 0, col: 7"
8: "row: 0, col: 8"
9: "row: 0, col: 9"
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[10]
0: "row: 1, col: 0"
1: "row: 1, col: 1"
2: "row: 1, col: 2"
3: "row: 1, col: 3"
4: "row: 1, col: 4"
5: "row: 1, col: 5"
6: "row: 1, col: 6"
7: "row: 1, col: 7"
8: "row: 1, col: 8"
9: "row: 1, col: 9"
length: 10
...
```

However, what instead is logged (in Chrome) shows the row as being '0' for each iteration.
Not only that, if I change the iteration rules to not go to 0, it shows whichever the last 'row' would be for all sub arrays of the 'myRows' set of arrays.

Really scratching my head at this one, is there something about the push() method that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a **new** `cols` array each time through the outer loop. You're using the same `cols` array for each row, and modifying it in place, because `myRows.push(myCols)` pushes a reference to that array, it doesn't make a copy.

Change:

```
myCols.length = 0;
```

to:

```
myCols = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `myCols` is a reference to an array.

`myRows.push(myCols);` puts that value into the array referenced by `myRows`.

In your code, that is always *the same array*.

`myCols.length = 0;` removes the contents of that array.

---

You need to create a new array each time you go around the loop.

Replace `myCols.length = 0;` with `myCols = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly adding the same object over and over for each column.  You need to create a new `Array` on each pass:

```
var myCols = [];
for (r=4; r>=0; r--) {
    myCols = new Array(); // or temp = [];
    for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
        myCols.push("row: " + r +", col: " + c);
    }
    myRows.push(myCols);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this issue because javascript arrays are stored by reference. You are not  creating new columns in the outer loop but instead overriding the existing columns and only pushing a new reference to the same columns array into the rows array. Essentially your rows array is an array of 5 references to the same columns array.

To overcome this you must create a new myCols array in the outer loop as such:

```
var myRows = [];  // array of 'column' arrays

for (r=4; r>=0; r--) {
    var myCols = [];  // 'buffer' for each column
    for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
        myCols.push("row: " + r +", col: " + c);
}
myRows.push(myCols);
}
console.log(myRows);
```